# Need JS Pattern Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

Need help creating a validation pattern in javascript for a field.

The value entered must be formatted as follows: xxxxxx-NN-x-NNNN

x = letters or numbers;  N = numbers only

Pattern must include the dashes '-' at js positions 6,9,11.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please show some effort

Comment: jQuery has a validation mask plugin

Comment: @ T McKeown Unfortunatly not using jQuery.

Comment: `/^[A-Z]{6}-\d{2}-[A-Z]-\d{4}$/`

Comment: @Ejay Thanks Ejay. However, these type of things in JS are very confusing to me and looking for someone to help point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Alex K.  Thanks Alex, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Alex K. Wouldn't it be like this if it can be letter or numbers?
/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-\d{2}-[A-Z]-\d{4}$/

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought x was letters only

Comment: @Alex - Can you answer and I'll give you credit?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6}-\d{2}-[A-Za-z0-9]-\d{4}$/
```

Or shorter with the *case insensitive* flag:

```
/^[A-Z0-9]{6}-\d{2}-[A-Z0-9]-\d{4}$/i
```